# Using Angular Template-driven Forms for User Login/Sign Up

Tags: forms, angular, angular-reactive-forms

as the title says, I'm trying to use a template-driven Angular form for providing the user a way to sign up and login. I've read a lot about the disadvantages of using template-driven forms when complex validation is required. However, this is not the case here. My question is: are there other disadvantages (that are not instantly evident or that may appear later) in using template-driven forms for such functionality when one usually starts with a clean form and submits data once really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only been working with Angular (as opposed to AngularJS) for a couple of months, but for your simple scenario, I think that a Template-driven form is preferred.

You only need one-way data-binding, and you presumably only have two (or only a small handful of) entry fields, with simple validation requirements (do you need more than "required"?).

I think that Reactive Forms would be overkill here.